# Should CaS-WebApp-Server and Cas-Management-webapp beoverlayed in the same project

Tags: cas, jasig

I am looking into implementing single sign on functionality for my applications. I am looking into CAS and since I am new to this I wanted to ask it here since the documentation related to the CAS is not complete or accurate.

Cas version - 4.0.x
I have overlayed cas-server-webapp and bought up the login page.

1) Should Cas-server-webapp and cas-management-webapp be overlayed into a single project ?? (Please note version is 4.0.x)

2) If so, could anyone provide the correct url for the management-webapp?? Is it
https://localhost:8443/cas/services/ or  https://localhost:8443/management/. If it is the latter shouldn't there be cas/management??

3) Could you point me to a tutorial or sample project implementing both. The jasig documentation is not clear to me.

My current pom

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>cas</warName>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/spring-configuration/log4jConfiguration.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </overlay>
                    <overlay>
                      <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cas-management-webapp</artifactId>
                        <excludes>
                          <exclude>WEB-INF/spring-configuration/log4jConfiguration.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-support-generic</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-management-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <cas.version>4.0.1</cas.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ja-sig</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/ </url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Is this the correct process? Please let me know if I am going abvout this completely wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a current example project. https://github.com/leleuj/cas-overlay-demo

You should be able to get to the cas management app with /cas-management once your app is built.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I have managed to get the server and management webapps working.

Comment: @john-mercier Quick question, is the link you provided suggesting that the overlay demo you referenced combines both the cas and cas-mgmt app into the same project as _ananth_ is asking about? I haven't tried it yet but would definitely be interested to know if thats the case before I run to do it myself.  Thanks please advise.